# Lookup and Choose function combined in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem, where I am trying to use Worksheet.Function.Lookup combined with Worksheet.Function.Choose.
I have determined two variables which are used to determine the lookup and choose values.
I am basically using the lookup function to first find a value matching the first variable.
After I have found the value, I want to use the choose function inside the lookup in order to return the corresponding range determined by the choose functions index number, which is determined by another variable.

This code gives me "Run-time error 1004: Unable to get the Lookup property of the WorksheetFunction class"

I am basically trying to replicate the LOOKUP function from an old Excel 4.0 macro

Any advise?

```
Sub Mysub()

Dim X As Long
Dim Y As Long
Dim Z As Integer

Y = 22.5
Z = 3

Windows("My file.xlsm").Activate ' Activates the file with the data
Worksheets("My sheet").Activate ' Activates the correct sheet
X = Worksheet.Function.Lookup(Y, Range("A1:A201").Value, WorksheetFunction.Choose(Z, Range("C1:C201").Value, Range("B1:B201").Value, Range("D1:D201").Value))

End Sub
```

Desired output: Value from the D column that is on the same row as variable Y in the A column
Current output: Error

Answer (score 1):

### A VBA Lookup: Using Match and Index (Late-Bound)

- Use `Option Explicit` at the top of each module and it will detect errors at compile time i.e. before the code runs e.g. it would have alerted you that you have a typo: `Worksheet.Function` should be `WorksheetFunction`.

**A Quick Fix**

- You could get away with something like the following but I wouldn't recommend it i.e. if there is no match, an error will occur.

```vb
Sub MysubQF()

    Dim X As Variant ' could be anything
    Dim Y As Double ' decimal number
    Dim Z As Long ' whole number
    
    Y = 22.5
    Z = 3
    
    With Workbooks("My file.xlsm").Worksheets("My sheet")
        X = WorksheetFunction.Index( _
                WorksheetFunction.Choose( _
                    Z, .Range("C1:C201"), .Range("B1:B201"), .Range("D1:D201")), _
                WorksheetFunction.Match(Y, .Range("A1:A201"), 0))
    End With
    
    MsgBox X

End Sub
```

**A Study**

- Play reasonably with the constants (except for the workbook and worksheet names) and observe the behavior of the code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Mysub()

    Const SRC_WORKBOOK As String = "My file.xlsm"
    Const SRC_WORKSHEET As String = "My sheet"
    Const SRC_LOOKUP_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const SRC_LOOKUP_VALUE As Double = 22.5
    
    Const SRC_RETURN_COLUMNS As String = "B,C,D"
    Const SRC_RETURN_COLUMN_INDEX As Long = 3
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks(SRC_WORKBOOK)
    ' If this code is in the same workbook, you can instead simply use:
    'Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets(SRC_WORKSHEET)
    
    Dim slrg As Range, srCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range(SRC_LOOKUP_FIRST_CELL)
        srCount = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If srCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data
        Set slrg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With
    
    Dim srCols() As String: srCols = Split(SRC_RETURN_COLUMNS, ",")
    
    If UBound(srCols) + 1 < SRC_RETURN_COLUMN_INDEX Then
        MsgBox "Cannot index column " & SRC_RETURN_COLUMN_INDEX & ". " _
            & "There are only " & UBound(srCols) + 1 & " columns.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim srCol As String:
    srCol = Application.Index(srCols, SRC_RETURN_COLUMN_INDEX)
    
    Dim srIndex: srIndex = Application.Match(SRC_LOOKUP_VALUE, slrg, 0)
    
    If IsError(srIndex) Then
        MsgBox "The value " & SRC_LOOKUP_VALUE & " was not found " _
            & "in column """ & srCol & """.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns(srCol)
    Dim srCell As Range: Set srCell = srrg.Cells(srIndex)
    
    Dim Result As Variant: Result = srCell.Value

    MsgBox "The result is """ & Result & """. It was found in cell """ _
        & srCell.Address(0, 0) & """.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Range("A1:A201").Value` attempts to get one single value from 200 cells, not 200 different values. For example, try the simple `?Range("A1:A2").Value` to see the same error.

Just use `Range("A1:A201")` etc. for all of your ranges

The other problem you may not have noticed yet: `22.5` is not `Long`. If you want to use decimals, `Dim Y As Double`. Otherwise the macro will work, but it will give you an incorrect result.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the "Activate" with a direct reference to the book and sheet. In Choose you had the .Value while you had to return a Range. To make this obvious and to make the code easy to read I moved the Choose out of the Lookup. Finally, the value returned by Lookup should be used somewhere, so I made the Sub Function and return the found value.

```
Public Function MyFunc() As Long
   Dim Y As Long, Z As Integer, ws As Worksheet, r As Range
   
   Y = 22.5
   Z = 3
   
   Set ws = Workbooks("My file.xlsm").Worksheets("My sheet")
   Set r = WorksheetFunction.Choose(Z, ws.Range("C1:C201"), ws.Range("B1:B201"), ws.Range("D1:D201"))
   MyFunc = WorksheetFunction.Lookup(Y, ws.Range("A1:A201").Value, r)
End Function
```